# Can Chrome tools show the NTLM negotiation process?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, ntlm

Chrome and other browsers support Windows Authentication via NTLM. From what I can tell though, the Chrome Dev Tools Network tab only ever shows the initial request and final response in the negotiation process. (See diagram below)
[image: NTLM Authentication]

Image credit: https://www.zevenet.com/knowledge-base/howtos/load-balancing-of-webapps-with-iis-authentication-ntlm-and-asp-net-impersonation/

Is there a way to make in the tool it show all the detail about what's actually going on? It's very confusing to look at the initial request and not see any Authorization header yet have the server respond with a response indicating the client is now authorized.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is WireShark capture.